# C# find already existing object instance using a string

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I the value of a string variable as an instance name?
Here is some code:

```
    TabItem selectedTabItem = this.mainTabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;
    Type t = selectedTabItem.DataContext.GetType();
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("SelectAll");

    //Here is the problem
    method.Invoke(t, null);
```

It exists 5 different classes (**UserManager.cs, GroupManager.cs, PrinterManager.cs, FontManager.cs, ...)** and everyone of these classes have the functions `SelectAll()`, `UnselectAll`, `RemoveSelected`. Now I dont want to create something like this:

```
        TabItem selectedTabItem = this.mainTabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;

        if (selectedTabItem.Name == "UserManager")
        {
            if (btnSelectAll == pressed)
            {
                this.UserManager.SelectAll();
            }
            else if (btnUnselectAll == pressed)
            {
                this.UserManager.UnselectAll();
            }
            else if (btnRemoveSelected == pressed)
            {
                this.UserManager.RemoveSelected();
            }
        }
        else if (selectedTabItem.Name == "PrinterManager")
        {
            if (btnSelectAll == pressed)
            {
                this.PrinterManager.SelectAll();
            }
            //...
        }
        else if (selectedTabItem.Name == "GroupManager")
        {

        }
        //...
```

Now this line here:

```
method.Invoke(t, null);
```

It works fine, but I dont want to create a new instance. I need a existing instance. Now I could write

```
method.Invoke(this.UserManager, null);
```

But I think this way is not that good, because I will need again much if/else.

I need something like this:

```
string instance = "this.UserManager";
method.Invoke(instance, null);
```

Comment: There is no way to *find* instance. It's you who have to supply it. Consider putting instances inside some list when you create one (e.g. `static List<SomeBaseTypeOrInterface>`). It can be a `Dictionary<string, SomeBaseTypeOrInterface>` if you want to find it by using that string.

Comment: Go ahead with your solution, providing you want to end up with a totally unreadable, messy code. Just sayin'…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that can be solved by making use of a **Custom Control** that extends `TabItem`. This custom `TabItem` will need a *manager* assigned to it.

Firstly, you'll need an interface for your manager implementations.

```
public interface IManager
{
    SelectAll();
    UnselectAll();
    RemoveSelected();
}
```

Then of course, you'll need some implementations:

```
public class UserManager : IManager
{
    //IManager methods
}
```

You'll then need a `TabItem` which can hold an `IManager`. Here's an example:

```
public class ManagedTabItem : TabItem
{
    public IManager Manager
    {
        get { return (IManager)GetValue(ManagerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ManagerProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ManagerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Manager", typeof(IManager), typeof(ManagedTabItem), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    static ManagedTabItem()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ManagedTabItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ManagedTabItem)));
    }
}
```

You may want to read up on **Custom Controls**, you can find a nice tutorial [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx).

---

Now, to **bring this all together** you simply need to replace existing `TabItem` with the new `ManagedTabItem` and assign the `Manager` property.

```
<local:ManagedTabItem Manager="{Binding UserManager}" ... />
```

The above method assumes you are making use of `DataContext` and `Binding`. Otherwise, you can of course do this in code behind instead:

```
myTabItem.Manager = UserManager;
```

The beauty of this method is now you **don't** need to check *which* `TabItem` was clicked, instead you can simply call whatever method you need to on the tab's assigned manager.

```
ManagedTabItem selectedTabItem = this.mainTabControl.SelectedItem as ManagedTabItem;

if (btnSelectAll == pressed)
{
    selectedTabItem.Manager.SelectAll();
}
...
```

That was quite a large workaround, however there's nothing wrong with keeping things extensible and allowing changes to be *easy*.